# Does specific IE rules in <head> works for JS too?

Tags: javascript, html, css, head

I'm wondering if this code works or not:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
      <script src="/assets/v3/application_ie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <link href="/assets/v3/application_ie.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <![endif]-->
```

I always saw these kind of rules with CSS only, so I'm wondering about javascript here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

In HTML, anything contained within `<!-- ... -->` is a comment. Anything contained within this comment block will be treated as a comment and not rendered as HTML (and ultimately not displayed on the page). Older versions of IE will parse through HTML comments looking for its square bracket notation and will render the HTML within if a match is made.

Do note, however, that conditional comments like these are no longer supported in modern versions of IE.

Comment: What do you mean by `modern`? IE is such a mess that even the 11 is not modern at all...

Comment: @Vadorequest the word "modern" refers to the present day. IE11 and future versions do not support these conditional statements.

Comment: So they will be ignored I guess? It won't mess up the application itself?

Comment: @Vadorequest Pretty sure - from personal experience - that IE11 is (as of this writing) better than Chrome. It may not support everything, but the things it does support are supported better. You tried doing CSS animations in Chrome?

Comment: @Vadorequest they will be treated as comments and nothing more.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Sure some things are better, but honnestly from my own experience, there are many stuff that are supported by chrome, FF, opera, safari, even their mobile versions that are still not supported by IE11 yet. So, I wouldn't say IE is better.

Comment: @Vadorequest Vendor prefixes don't count as "supported". Chrome has at least three different ways to define a simple gradient. That's not "supporting", that's "jumping the gun on a standard that hasn't been fixed yet"

Answer (score 3):

You can have anything you want in a conditional comment.

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]><p>Update your damn browser!</p><![endif]-->
```

But you get frowny faces from some people (like me) for having to hax older browsers into working ;) If you need compatibility back there, you should avoid using features that mess up.

Comment: I do not need any compatibility for < 8, so I guess that's okay.